# How can I insert a new cell section into an existing UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm a beginner in developing iOS App. I'm creating a login view for my app. I have a existing `UITextView` which has already contained 4 sections. Each section only contain one cell in one row.

My `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method looks like:

```
-- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     if(indexPath.section == 0)
     {   return cellEmail;   }
     else if(indexPath.section == 1)
     {  return cellPassword;  }
     else if(indexPath.section == 2)
     {  return cellLoginButton;   }
     else return cellFacebookLogin;
     return nil;
}
```

The code that showing above, `cellEmail` contains `emailTextField`, `cellPassword` contains `passwordTextField`, `cellLoginButton` contains `LoginButton`, and `cellFacebookLogin` contains `FacebookButton` . Both of them are already registered and shown on screen successfully.

For now, I would like to insert one section which contains one cell for the forget password button.

I mean, How can I insert a new section with a new `cellForgetPassword` between `cellPassword` and `cellLoginButton`?

I have try the code like this, but it doesn't work:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
     [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"cellForgetPassword" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cellForgetPassword"];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     UITableViewCell *cellForgetPassword = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellForgetPassword" forIndexPath:indexPath];

     if(indexPath.section == 0) { return cellEmail; }
     else if(indexPath.section == 1) {return cellPassword; }
     else if(indexPath.section == 2) {return cellForgetPassword;}
     else if(indexPath.section == 3) {return cellLoginButton;}
     else return cellFacebook;

     return nil;
}
```

How can I solve this problem? Thank you so much!

Comment: Is that your real code for `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`? You don't use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`?

Comment: That is the code before using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` . I try to use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` , but it still cannot be obtained the cell. Then, I realized that the cell might not be registered, so I added `registerNib:` in `viewDidLoad`. However, it reported that the identifier did not found as it was not registered as a class or nib. I don't know why.

Comment: i didn't understand want you want exactly doing?
do you see your 4 cells on the tableview or not?

Comment: Yes, I do. They work well.

Comment: try to increment number of sections in :
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
And then add your Cell as you did it for the previous cells

Comment: Still not work. It reported that `Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/Eddy/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/24F168FC-F8C8-4CA8-B70C-EE901CD5756D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/EA37BAD9-24A0-4621-94E5-0FCC01E04A37/MonkeyChatter.app> (loaded)' with name 'cellForgetPassword'`

Comment: @HarrisZhang, Visit the properties of the .xib files in the file inspector ，the property "Target Membership" pitch on the select box,

Comment: I have checked the properties, and "Target Membership" has already been selected. The `cellForgetPassword` of the .xlb files was added seperately with the code. I was thinking that the `cellForgetPassword` maybe still not connect with the code.

Comment: Thanks for everyone. Problem has been solved. As the cell in .xlb file didn't connect with view's owner, it couldn't be registered successfully.